# How to include 3rd party node modules (website-scraper) in electron app that uses electron-prebuilt

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules, node-serialport

I have created an electron (windows) app with electron-prebuilt, native node modules and python server. I want to include other node modules like serial-port and web-scraper with my app. I have installed the modules with npm and the modules get bundled in "app.asar" file. But on using the module with require method in my javascript function throwing "cannot find the module" error. What to do?

Comment: Maybe, https://github.com/electron/asar

Comment: I couldn't find a solution. I have seen that want to build the electron framework again but it throwing error.